# nodejs gmail api not supporting promises

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

Google [recommends using promises](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises), but its code examples do not, and I'm struggling to make the gmail api work with promises when I modify the code from the [online docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).

All I've changed are the lines below, but I get an error

> VM677:5 Uncaught TypeError: gmail.users.messages.list(...).then is not a function

```
gmail.users.messages.list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    labelIds: 'Label_14'
// }, function(err, response) {
//     if (err) {
//         console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
//         return;
//     }
//     console.log(response);
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("success", response);
})
```

Most of the [examples of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574755/why-cant-i-use-gapi-client-gmail-users-labels-list) use promises so I think it should be possible but I can't see what the problem is. Would really welcome some help

Comment: i added a link to an example, and see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises

Comment: You're looking at the wrong docs.  That link (about promises) refers to the [client-side (browser) google js library](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js).  You're using the [server-side `googleapis` module](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs); its docs make clear that it does not support promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `googleapis` module does not support promises.

Consider using [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) if you want to use promises with this module.

```
var list = util.promisify(gmail.users.messages.list);

list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    labelIds: 'Label_14'
})
.then(...);
```

Comment: Promises support was added in March 2018: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/pull/1091