# Gmail API "Delegation denied for email" error while reading delegating email from a superadmin account

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

I have been trying to get emails from another user in my domail in order to migrate it, using the google nodejs library. My account is superadmin and my API has wide-domain delegation permission enable with the following scopes:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration",
"https://mail.google.com/",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing"
```

I have logged into the API usin an impersonate access

```
async function initializeGmail(emailToImpersonate) {
        const auth = await getAuth(emailToImpersonate);
        return google.gmail({
            version: 'v1',
            auth
        });
    }

    async function getAuth(emailToImpersonate) {
        const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            client_email,
            null,
            private_key,
            SCOPES,
            emailToImpersonate
        );
        await jwtClient.authorize();
        return jwtClient;
    }
```

I have added delegation permitions in the account I want to migrate so I can access its emails from my main account

```
const requestBody = {
        delegateEmail: user.email,
        verificationStatus: 'accepted'
}
await gmail.users.settings.delegates.create({userId, requestBody})
```

I request the emails of the account to migrate and I get the following error

```
const gmail = await initializeGmail(userEmail);
const messages =  (await gmail.users.messages.list({auth, userId:userEmail})).data.messages;
```

```
code: 403,
errors: [
    {
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden',
      message: 'Delegation denied for sysadmin@boatjump.com'
    }
]
```

Any help or ideas will be highly appreciated

Comment: Is the `delegate.Email` `user.email`  the email of the account to migrate or your main account?

Comment: I want to delegate an account to my main account

Answer (score 0):

### 1st step - Create a delegate

- To create a delegate, the parameter `delegateEmail` must specify the primary email of the delegate, that is your main account, I assume `sysadmin@boatjump.com`
- As specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/create), the delegate creation must performed by a service account that impersonates the delegator (your secondary account, I assume `user.email`)

### 2nd step - list the delegator's emails

- Authenticate as `sysadmin@boatjump.co'` (no need for service account)
- Specify as `userId` `user.email`

> The reason you obtained a 403 error is the fact you specified
>   `user.email` instead of `sysadmin@boatjump.com` as the delegate and
>   thus did not pass to `sysadmin@boatjump.com` the authority to list
>   `user.email`'s emails.

UPDATE:

If after a correct set-up of a delegate you continue experiencing issues with retrieving the delegator's emails, this issue is likely related to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760064) behavior already reported on Google's Issue Tracker.

I recommend you to give it a "star" to increase visibility and the chances that it will be fixed in the future.

**Workaround for the meantime:**

When using the service account with domain-wide delegation, authenticate as the delegator and retrieve the emails on his behalf (userId:"me").

Comment: It's possible that I have explained myself wrong but my main gmail's account is user.email and the accoutn that I want to delegate is userEmail

Comment: What is then sysadmin@boatjump.com?

Comment: user.email = sysadmin, userEmail = email that I want to migrate

Comment: And `emailToImpersonate`is the same like `userEmail`? What about `userId` in `gmail.users.settings.delegates.create({userId, requestBody})`?

Comment: Yes emailToImpersonate is the same that userEmail and userId is the ID of the userEmail

Comment: The issue seems related to the fact that you do not authenticate a as the service account `gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: jwtClient });` when performing the request `gmail.users.settings.delegates.create({userId, requestBody})`, so your request is not succesful. I recommend you to list delegates for `emailToImpersonate` to verify that the creation of delegates has been performed succesfully. Also, `verificationStatus: 'accepted'` is a readonly value, do no specify it in your resource body.

Comment: I use this lane 
`(await gmail.users.settings.delegates.list({userId})).data.delegates`
And my response is 
`[
  {
    delegateEmail: 'sysadmin@boatjump.com',
    verificationStatus: 'accepted'
  }
]`

Comment: And to retrieve the emails, why do you define `const gmail = await initializeGmail(userEmail);` - that is you do not identify as `sysadmin@boatjump.com`? Try to retrieve the emails without service account, auhtenticated with the crendetials of `sysadmin@boatjump.com`, something like `const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: 'me',
  }, (err, res) => {...`. A reason for your problem is that you seem to use promises, which is [not supported by googleapsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400116/nodejs-gmail-api-not-supporting-promises)

Comment: but If I use to read emails `userId:'me'` I will read my emails and I want to read the emails of the other account.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant `const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth}); gmail.users.labels.list({ userId: userEmail, }, (err, res) => {...`

Comment: I have the same problem. res values is undefined and err values is `errors: [
    {
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden',
      message: 'Delegation denied for sysadmin@boatjump.com'
    }
  ]`

Comment: And both emails are Gmail / GSuite accounts?

Comment: Yes and the two stay in the same company.

Comment: I found a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760064) on Google's Issue Tracker that is related to your issue! I initially assumed that your issue is due to erroneous delegation, but if your delegation is successful, your permission error msut be related to the bug. I will update my answer.